# How to get the next sequence value in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Current I have a problem in finding the next sequence value of the column.

The `my_list` table is created by

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_list_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
my_list (id int PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('my_list_id_seq'),
mycardno);
ALTER SEQUENCE my_list_id_seq OWNED BY my_list.id;
```

I tried to use currval query to find the next sequence value (should be 1) but I get

```
SELECT currval('my_list_id_seq');
ERROR:  currval of sequence "my_list_id_seq" is not yet defined in this session
```

If I use nextval query, I will get 2, which is not I want and the sequence will increase 1 by this Query.

```
SELECT nextval('my_list_id_seq');

 nextval
---------
       2
(1 row)
```

After the nextval query, I can now use currval query.

```
SELECT currval('my_list_id_seq');

 currval
---------
       2
(1 row)
```

As I cannot find other solution at this stage, currently my step to get the is to

1. Do nextval and get the "next sequence" value
2. Use `ALTER SEQUENCE my_list_id_seq RESTART WITH "next sequence - 1";` to set back the sequence value. The "next sequence - 1" is done by C# (I use WPF).

I would like to know if there are direct approach for this problem. Thank you.

Comment: You've already got an answer how to get the current value, but for what do you need it? You can't assume that the value you get won't get incremented until the next record get's inserted. Moreover, the value can even get incremented if a transaction fails and you will get a gap in the `id` column.

Comment: After creating the sequence you will not get `2` when you call `nextval()` but 1. So I don't really understand what your problem is.

Comment: It sounds like you don't ever need the value of the sequence. Try to explain your goal, how your second table looks alike (simplified). Put these details in your question, not in the comments.

Comment: @testcb00 please [edit] your question and add all those explanations to it

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I edited, but my problem is solved by richyen's solution. All I want is to get the current value and the last_value column from my_list_id_seq do the job.

Comment: That sounds like a strange thing to do. Especially in an environment with concurrent access I don't think you can rely on that value. What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve with that approach?

Comment: It's still not clear what your goal is. Your two tables doesn't relate in any way. If you look for the last existing id in my_list, simply select max(id). If you are inserting a new record in it, get the new records id.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68819917/if-two-tables-data-are-independant-but-they-have-relationship-is-it-necessary I make a new question about the design, maybe it will give a clear view of my problem and why I need the strange method of getting the last sequence value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html), `currval` only works when `nextval` has been called in a session:

> Returns the value most recently obtained by `nextval` for this sequence in the current session. (An error is reported if `nextval` has never been called for this sequence in this session.)

If you want to get the current value, you may want to try `SELECT * FROM my_list_id_seq` and use the corresponding value from the `last_value` column:

```
postgres=# CREATE SEQUENCE my_list_id_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE
postgres=# CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
my_list (id int PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('my_list_id_seq'),
mycardno int);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# ALTER SEQUENCE my_list_id_seq OWNED BY my_list.id;
ALTER SEQUENCE
postgres=# select * from my_list_id_seq;
 last_value | log_cnt | is_called 
------------+---------+-----------
          1 |       0 | f
(1 row)
```

Comment: Selecting from the sequence gives you a snapshotted value, just like the misnamed/broken `currval()`. `READ UNCOMMITTED` or `WITH (NOLOCK)` would help, as would a `currval()` implementation that doesn't lie. As it stands the OP's approach - `nextval()` followed by `ALTER SEQUENCE` - seems to be the only option for punching through transaction/session boundaries, but of course it requires additional locking ...

Comment: Note: it seems that there is a functioning `currval()` after all, but it is called `pg_sequence_last_value()` and it is undocumented. Some aspects of its behaviour may be weird, though - see https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/16018-e617465560d648c5%40postgresql.org