# If two Table's data are independant, but they have relationship (one Main, another Sub). What is the best way to link them?

Tags: c#, postgresql

Currently I am designing a Customer Management System, which include Customer's Company Information and their Contacts.

My design is in below photo.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FecUU.png

In this photo, you can see `Label` and `TextBox` of **Customer ID, Company Name, Address Line, Company Tel, Fax, Pay Terms and a Group of Contact, Tel, Email**.

In my past design, I created a Table to store all the data, and named the group as multiple columns `contact_1, tel_1, email_1, contact_2, ... email_8`. This design allow me to easy query the data but bad in **data binding**. So I think I should make a new design for this.

My new design is to separate the **Group of Contact, Tel, Email** to another Table. So that the list will remain the **Customer ID, Company Name, Address Line, Company Tel, Fax and Pay Terms**. The list (without **AddressLine1 ... AddressLine4**) are showed in this Page design).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OINI.png

The left column is the `id` column which I used for edit action (use `SELECT columns FROM customer_list WHERE id='id'` in the Edit Window, `id` is obtained by `(this.CustomerDataGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView)["id"]`). I have set `Visibility.Collapsed` to hide the `id` column in `C#` code for better view.

However, since I should not make a Table inside a Table, the data of **Contact, Tel, Email** (Customer Contact List) will be `INSERT` in another Table as `contact, tel, email` column. Then I have to find way to **link** the Customer Contact List's Table to the Customer List.

As no data is created at this stage, I think if I can find the **last_value** of the **id** column sequence of the Customer List's data, then I can create a Customer Contact List's Table which is related to the Customer List's data.

The solution I found is to use `SELECT last_value FROM customer_list_id_seq` to get the **last_valu**e. After the query, I make a variable `current_value = last_value + 1` to get the next sequence value. With this value, I can create a table `customer_contact_list_@current_value` which is "related" to the non-created Customer List's data.

I know that I could save the **non-Customer Contact List** data first and get the **last** `id` value of `customer_list` by `SELECT id FROM customer_list ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`. My concern is that: If I have to add more Contact, I still able to make a new design, convert the Group of **Contact, Tel, Email** to a `DataGrid` in `WPF`.

**As I am new to programming, my mindset and design knowledge are only in basic stage.**
In this design, the data are separated in two Table which means that they have **no relationship**.

I have to make the Customer Contact List's Table name related to customer_list.id to make them like having a relationship. Also, in this design, I have to created a new Customer Contact List's Table for each Customer List's Data (row).

I would like to know if there are better approach of this design.

My another design is to add three columns to the customer_list table., but then my Query will be complex as I have to make duplicate "Customer ID, Company Name, Address Line, Company Tel, Fax, Pay Terms" and try to filter them. Even if I set the other 7's row duplicate value to null, the table will look hard to read.

Comment: It seems that what I need is to learn about the Database Normalization. I should not create a new Table for each row in customer_list. I should create a customer_contact_list with a column which is Foreign Key and REFERENCES to customer_list(customer_id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are on your with the last comment creating a Foreign Key. So we have a relationship between Customers and Contacts. However the outstanding question becomes what type is Customer:Contact relationship?

- One-to-One (1:1)   -> Each Customer has one contact and a Contact is for one customer.
- One-to-Many (1:M)  -> Each Customer has many contacts and a Contact is for one customer.
- Many-to-Many (M:M) -> Each customer has Many Contacts and Each Contact is for many customers.

From your description discard 1:1. For 1:M the you include the customer PK in the contact table. For the M:M you actually create another table that contains the PK from both Customer and Contact.  
As for generating ids do not even try to get the **last one** and increment it (generally referred to as MAX+1). In a multiple user environment it is a virtual guarantee you will get a duplicate. Simply create a [sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createsequence.html) or a [generated identity](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-identity-column/) for each table and Postgres will handle it.  

Tables for 1:M, Postgres v10 and above

```
create table customers( cust_id    integer generated always as identity  
                      , address    text
                      , tel        text
                      , fax        text
                      , pay_terms  text
                      , constraint cust_pk primary key (cust_id)
                      ) 
                      
 create table contacts( cont_id    integer generated always as identity 
                      , cust_id    interger 
                      , tel        text
                      , email      text
                      , constraint cont_pk primary key (cont_id)
                      , constraint cont_2_cust_fk 
                                   foreign key (cust_id)
                                   references customers(cust_id) 
                      );
```

Table definitions for M:M, Postgres v10 and above

```
create table customers( cust_id    integer generated always as identity  
                      , address    text
                      , tel        text
                      , fax        text
                      , pay_terms  text
                      , constraint cust_pk primary key (cust_id)
                      ) 
                      
create table contacts( cont_id    integer generated always as identity 
                     , cust_id    interger 
                     , tel        text
                     , email      text
                     , constraint cont_pk primary key (cont_id)
                     );
                      
create table customer_contacts( cust_id integer
                              , cont_id integer
                              , constraint cust_cont_pk 
                                           primary key (cust_id, cont_id)
                              , constraint cust_cont_2_cust_fk 
                                           foreign key (cust_id)
                                           references customers(cust_id)  
                              , constraint cust_cont_2_cont_fk 
                                           foreign key (cont_id)
                                           references contacts(cont_id)
                              );
```

For Postgres versions prior to v10, replace `integer generated always as identity` by `serial`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would like to know if creating a sequence seq with nextval(seq) is better or just use the SERIAL.

Comment: They are exactly the same. `SERIAL` is not actually a datatype as it would appear. It is a shortcut: It creates a sequence and an integer data type and  makes nextval(seq)  the default value. It you look at it afterward there is no way to tell whether it was serial or independent definitions.  The same goes `BIGSERIAL` except it creates a bigint data type.